# How to get the data onto my webpage

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have this code and i am not sure what to put to in the code to make the data show up. I have the headers but i just need help with the data.

```
  public string wogrid()
    {
      string htmlStr = "";
      SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * owner";
      con.Open();
      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      while (reader.Read())
      {
        int OwnerID = reader.GetInt32(0);
        string OwnerID = reader.GetString(1);
        int  = reader.GetInt32(2);
        string location = reader.GetString(3);               
      }

      con.Close();
      return htmlStr;
    }

    /*****source code must me like ******/

    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0"    bgcolor="#EAEAEA" >
    <tr align="center" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;" >
    <td width="20%"> OwnerID </td>                        
    <td width="20%"> fname </td>            
    <td width="20%">lname</td>  
    <td width="20%">street</td>
    <td width="20%">zip</td> 
    <td width="20%">phone</td>                       
  ![enter image description here][1]   </tr>
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with so many different languages?  Which language do you require an answer for?  Please remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: What front-end language are you using? If ASP.NET or MVC, you can generate a dataset and datatable, then set it to a gridview.

Comment: Shouldn't that query be `SELECT * from owner`?

Comment: its asp.net @IanLink

Comment: You are backing the wrong horse :) Check [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETGridView-5b16ce70)

Comment: @yazanpro I already have most of the code in c# i just need to know how to get my data on to the page

Comment: There is a guy that is backing the right horse. Check his answer :)

Comment: @yazanpro no link came up if thats what u were trying to send

Comment: @Jake oh I see, that was from code.msdn.microsoft.com which is apparently blocked in your country. Anyway it's using Lan Link solution.

Comment: I understand that you feel you're almost there. But trust me populating a native HTML table with data is way more complicated than checking out GridView controls. BTW, tag your question with ASP.NET

Comment: @yazanpro this is for a school project and it has to be how i am doing it. Otherwise i would take your advise

Comment: If that's the case, then you have some heavy lifting to do. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation page, especially the Examples section.

Comment: @yazanpro can you revise it for me?

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I use to pull data programmatically and add to a ASPX front-End. This is just in addition to your existing code you referenced above.

C#:

```
public string wogrid()
{
    string htmlStr = "";
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * owner";
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ds.Tables.Add("Invoices");
    ds.Tables["Invoices"].Columns.Add("OwnerID");
    ds.Tables["Invoices"].Columns.Add("First Name");
    ds.Tables["Invoices"].Columns.Add("Last Name");
    ds.Tables["Invoices"].Columns.Add("Street");
    ds.Tables["Invoices"].Columns.Add("Zip");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Get your data by line.
        string1 = reader.GetInt32(0);
        string2 = reader.GetInt32(1);
        string3 = reader.GetInt32(2);
        string4 = reader.GetInt32(3);
        string5 = reader.GetInt32(4);
        ds.Tables["Invoices"].Rows.Add(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5 );
    }

    GridViewStatements.DataSource = ds;
    GridViewStatements.DataBind();
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewStatements" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Silver" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#99CCFF" SelectedIndex="0" Font-Size="Medium" RowStyle-Height="50px"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I added your code above to show where you could add it.

Comment: What part didn't work? Would you be more specific? This is code directly out of a DNN module I have written, it is a part of a button event click.